# Need a suitable Metric to indicate closeness between a set of expected vs observed values

Tags: metric

I have the expected ratio of four parameters A, B, C and D

`A :   B   :  C   :  D
        3.9 : 12.0 : 24.3 : 59.8`

I perform three experiments which provides me ratios of A,B,C and D.
As the results show, the ratios obtained in Experiment 1 are more closer to the Expected ratio
Experiment 3 seems to be the worst

`A :   B   :  C   :  D
Experiment 1    3.9 : 12.0 : 24.3 : 59.8 

Experiment 2    0.7 :  2.0 : 25.6 : 71.7 

Experiment 3    3.9 : 29.9 : 53.3 : 7.2`

Please suggest a single metric that can clearly indicate the closeness of values obtained in various experiments (as compared to the Expected ratio)

Need to do this for a lot of experiments

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'close'. Common choices would be mean absolute error, mean (absolute) relative error, mean square error, ...   $ \quad $ what are the values measuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the chi-square goodness of fit to measure similarity.

The more the deviation from theoretical expectation, the larger will the chi-square stat be.

Similar outcomes would mean chi-square stat would be small.

If you use R, this is a sample code:

expected_proportion=c(3.9 , 12.0 , 24.3 , 59.8)
chisq.test(table(outcomes),p=expected)